# How to Verify Huawei JWS for SysIntegrity using NodeJS

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to implement the server side check of a JWS token according to the docs: https://forums.developer.huawei.com/forumPortal/en/topic/0201531761922670112

I have also looked at the Java sample code: https://github.com/huaweicodelabs/SafetyDetect/tree/master/SysIntegrity/SafetyDetect-SysIntegrity-Server-Java-Demo

How do you verify the signature correctly in NodeJS?

I've tried using `jsonwebtoken`, `node-jose` and `jose` packages to no avail. Even trying with .pem, .cer and different formats for the Root CA..

This is the integrity token I am using:

```
REDACTED
```

JWT.io complains about the `==` at the end. I have tried all of the above without `==` and still can't get the signature to verify.

Any help to point me in the correct direction would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you question is off-top and not good asked. You have no clear problem, you want code. This is not a coding service. Rephrase your question for something specific. E.g.: "Check JWS with jose" and post the corresponding error message.  Complete the tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

```
const jose = require('node-jose');

const verifyResult = await jose.JWS.createVerify().verify(integrityToken, { allowEmbeddedKey: true });
```

I needed to add `allowEmbeddedKey: true`.